# ¿Cómo comprobar que la conexión a base de datos para JPA utiliza el pool de conexiones en persistence.xml?

Tags: java, jpa

Estoy aprendiendo Java EE con el libro "Java EE 7 with GlassFish 4". En la página 81 del libro detallan un archivo persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://
java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="customerPersistenceUnit">
<jta-data-source>jdbc/__CustomerDBPool</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Mi duda es sobre la etiqueta:

```
<jta-data-source>/__CustomerDBPool</jta-data-source>
```

Tengo creado un `connectionPool`, llamado `CustomerDBPool`, pero asumo que me faltan otros pasos para hacer que mi aplicación se conecte a PostgreSQL usando el código que muestra el libro.

¿Alguien sabe qué debo hacer para que mi aplicación se conecte a la base de datos basado en el archivo persistence.xml?

Comment: ¿Estás desplegando tu aplicación en un servidor de aplicaciones? ¿Has configurado el pool de conexión a base de datos en el servidor de aplicaciones y has comprobado que funciona? ¿Estás utilizando el mismo nombre del pool en tu archivo persistence.xml?

Comment: Estoy usando el ser Glassfish 4.1, tengo creado el pool de conexion a postgresql y testeado como exitosa la conexion y utilizo el mismo nombre de mi pool en el archivo persistence. Lo único que no he creado es un data source según la etiqueta <jta-data-source> ¿debo crear un data source? o JDNI?

Comment: Debes crear un acceso al pool de conexiones vía JNDI. Eso lo realizas en tu instancia de GlassFish. El nombre de tu pool en el JNDI es lo que irá en tu configuración de persistence.xml

Comment: Ok Luiggi. Ya hice creación del recurso JDBC y lo enlacé con el pool de conexiones. Ahora, según el libro indica que el archivo persistance.xml debe ser colocado en la ruta WEB-INF/classes/META-INFO/ dentro del archivo WAR. La verdad no se cual es esa ruta donde debo colocar mi archivo persistance.xml. Yo tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas: CustomerData1/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistance.xml, pero repito ignoro si es la correcta ubicación.

Comment: Entonces crea esa ruta de carpetas. Bajo WEB-INF crea una carpeta classes, y bajo classes crea una carpeta META-INF. En esta carpeta META-INF coloca tu archivo persistence.xml (no persistance.xml). El uso de resources/META-INF/persistence.xml es válido para aplicaciones de consola/escritorio.

Answer (score 1):

En *JEE* se debe realizar la configuración en el servidor de aplicaciones ([Glasfish](http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Glassfish/How_to_set_up_a_Connection_Pool), [Weblogic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/adf/oracle-weblogic-server-parte2-1942862-esa.html), [Jboss](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration), etc.) de un *DataSource* con el nombre que estás llamando en el **persistence.xml**, debido a que el tipo de conexión es *JTA* lo cual indica que el *pool* de conexiones lo maneja el servidor, por lo tanto, teniendo en cuenta esto debes verificar cómo se crea un `datasource` en el servidor de aplicaciones que estés usando y asignarle el *JNDI* el valor **jdbc/__CustomerDBPool**.